# $.post(url, data) doesn't work

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm creating simple twitter_clone using Rails to create json API and ReactJS in frontend.
What I need now is to save new created tweet into DB and then to update an API in json which contain list of tweets to be able to use them to render a view.
To achieve it I try to use post request:

**My add tweet function in main.jsx file**

```
addTweet(tweetToAdd){
    $.post("/tweets", { body: tweetToAdd })  //after saving to database
    .success( savedTweet => {
        let newTweetsList = this.state.tweetsList;
        newTweetsList.unshift(savedTweet);
        this.setState({tweetsList: newTweetsList}); 
    })
    .error(error => console.log(error));
}
```

There is a problem with delivering *body* of the tweet to database, cause after submitting there is NULL here.
Probably it means that body isn't send to DB ,but rest of parameters there are.

in /tweets there is an json API which looks like:

```
[{"id":17,"user_id":1,"body":null,"created_at":"2015-12-18T10:11:25.085Z","updated_at":"2015-12-18T10:11:25.085Z","name":"Marek Czyż"}]
```

When I create tweet manually form console everything works. so the problem must have been in previous piece of code.

Secondly after pressing SUBMIT tweet Ive recevied a warning that

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `TweetList`. See [fb.me/react-warning-keys](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children) for more information.

although Ive got a key to every Tweet:

let tweets = this.props.tweets.map(tweet => );

Please, help me.

Comment: Try to log the value of `tweetToAdd`. Is it empty? If not, it is possible your body param is not permitted in your controller. The waring you're seeing is related to the way you render your tweets. Can you share that code as well?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're passing the right value as `tweetToAdd`, make sure you [permit](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit) the `body` param in your controller. If it works in the console, it's not a validation problem, rather an unpermitted param.

As for the error you're seeing, you'll need to add a `key` prop to each rendered tweet. Something like:

```
render() {
  let tweets = this.props.tweets;
  return <ul>
    {tweets.map(tweet => {
      return <li key={tweet.id}>{tweet.body}</li>;
    })}
  </ul>;
}
```

Comment: yep, there was a problem with permission of :body. thanks!